# how to correctly use react Markdown and tailwindcss on a bulleted list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, tailwind-css, markdown

I would like to explain my problem of the day

I use react markdown and with it I display a bulleted list

so my problem and the next one, I use tailwindcss, and I am sure that I have a class conflict with react markdown

So I tried to get around the problem in the following way:

```
const CustomUl = ({ children, ...props }) => (
    <ul className="list-disc pl-6" {...props}>
        {children}
    </ul>
);
```

```
<Markdown  
className="markdown"
rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]}
remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]}
components={{
  ul: CustomUl,
  a: CustomLink,
}}>
{displayText()}
</Markdown>
```

so here it works correctly except that I still have a css problem

[image]

and so when I look at the classes in the html I have

[image]

and here I am deselecting the following classes

list-style-type: disc; and list-style: none;

the result is different and this is the one I would like to have at the end

[image]

if you have any ideas, thank you

Neff